# Trouble with creating an image_transport nodelet

Tags: callback, ros-noetic, nodelet, image-transport, compressed-image-transport

I'm working in ROS noetic on ubuntu 20.04

I'm pretty new to the concepts of nodelets but I felt I needed them to more efficiently go through a process of taking uncompressed images and then decompressing them with the [image_transport](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/image_transport/html/classimage__transport_1_1ImageTransport.html) package without it having to go through TCP. I went through the [pluginlib tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib/Tutorials/Writing%20and%20Using%20a%20Simple%20Plugin) and then [this tutorial for nodelets](https://automaticaddison.com/working-with-ros-nodelets-in-ros-noetic/), which I based my code off of.

I slightly altered it to first take normal images, which worked, but once I started working with the image_transport package, I've been encountering an error related to the callback signature.

Here is my main code where the commented out lines are the lines for the normal publisher/subscriber that worked with sensor_msgs/Image types.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/CompressedImage.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <nodelet/nodelet.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

namespace image_nodelet
{
    class Transport_Nodelet: public nodelet::Nodelet
    {
        public:
            Transport_Nodelet()
            {
            }
        private:
            virtual void onInit()
            {
                ros::NodeHandle nh = getPrivateNodeHandle();
                ros::NodeHandle im_nh = getNodeHandle();
                NODELET_DEBUG("Initializing nodelet...");

                image_transport::ImageTransport it(im_nh);
                
                sub_ = it.subscribe("/acl_jackal/forward/color/image_raw/compressed", 1, boost::bind(&Transport_Nodelet::callback, this, _1));
                pub_ = it.advertise("img_out", 1);

                //image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/acl_jackal/forward/color/image_raw/compressed", 1, &Transport_Nodelet::callback, this);
                //image_transport::Publisher pub = it.advertise("img_out", 1);

                // Create a publisher topic
                //pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("img_out",10); 
             
                // Create a subscriber topic
                //sub = nh.subscribe("/acl_jackal/forward/color/image_raw/compressed",10, &Transport_Nodelet::callback, this);  
            }
            // ros::Publisher pub;
            // ros::Subscriber sub;
            image_transport::Publisher pub_;
            image_transport::Subscriber sub_;

            void callback(const sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr& input)
            {

                try {
                    // Convert the compressed image ROS message to a cv::Mat using cv_bridge
                    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(input, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);

                    // Here cv_ptr->image contains the uncompressed image as cv::Mat

                    // You can now publish the uncompressed image if needed
                    pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
                } catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e) {
                    ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to 'bgr8'.", input->format.c_str());
                }
 
                // sensor_msgs::Image output;
                // output.data = input->data;

                // NODELET_DEBUG("msg data = %d",output.data);
                // ROS_INFO("msg data = %d",output.data);
                // pub.publish(output);        
            }
    };
    // Export the Hello_World class as a plugin using the
    // PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro.
    PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(image_nodelet::Transport_Nodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);
}
```

However, I get an error when I `catkin_make`:

```
/home/glenn/catkin_make_ws/src/my_workspace/src/my_nodelet.cpp:31:141:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:319:35: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, image_nodelet::Transport_Nodelet, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&>) (image_nodelet::Transport_Nodelet*&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
  319 |         unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);
```

This is referring to line 31 of my code which is:

```
sub_ = it.subscribe("/acl_jackal/forward/color/image_raw/compressed", 1, boost::bind(&Transport_Nodelet::callback, this, _1));
```

I followed the image_transport API documentation for the [callback signature](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/image_transport/html/classimage__transport_1_1ImageTransport.html#a1c847a2c719c874f84a78a6a60b98c7f), where the only difference is I used `sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr&` instead of `sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr&` which you can see in my callback function.

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried looking at all the documentation and forums but found no hints at a solution to my problem.

**Update**: I tried the obvious and just followed exactly as the document says for the callback, so I changed the argument type in the callback from

```
void callback(const sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr& input)
```

to

```
void callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& input)
```

With everything else the same, and it compiled. Does this mean I can't use the compressed image type with image_transport? I managed to already read uncompressed images so would I better off manually uncompressing without the image_transport package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your build error: if you look at image_transport.h, you'll see that the advertise() and subscribe() are defined only for ImageConstPtr objects. That's why it won't build if you pass a CompressedImageConstPtr object.

Not sure if you are aware of it, but the image_transport::ImageTransport class has a feature to automatically decompress a CompressedImage msg, then pass an ImageConstPtr object to your subscribe() callback. Take a look at this page:

http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/ExaminingImagePublisherSubscriber

Comment: I did notice that it didn't support the CompressedImageConstrPtr type. As for image_transport, I think the link only uses subscribe/publish in normal nodes, instead of in nodelets, which I'm trying to do. I was stuck because I was trying to get a callback within the nodelet for the CompressedImageConstPtr type which wasn't supported. But I can decompress by using CV bridge as shown in my code above. I don't know if I would really have any use of image_transport if I can already do this in a nodelet.

Comment: If you really want a sensor_msgs::CompressedImage, just subscribe to the topic normally and don't use the image_transport "helper" class.

Comment: Thanks. If I'm using a nodelet to subscribe and uncompress images, would it be recommended to also subscribe and republish an IMU message just for renaming purposes even though though the content doesn't have to be changed in any way? Right now I'm simply playing the bag file from a launch file and remapping topics from there but thought there might be timing discrepancies between uncompressed image topics coming from a nodelet and the IMU topic coming from the bag file node.

Comment: Please create a new question. If you think it helps with context, you can include a url back to this question.

Comment: Thank you Mike973. I will do that if I have any other questions.